# Custom X-axis in errorbar in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to customize X-axis range according to the X values, but it doesn't work. In the figure below, the first vertical line should map to 9, then second one 15, and 23 to the last one.
I tried the following:

```
%  use errorbar(x,y,...)
XLABEL=[9 15 23];
set(gca, 'Ticklength', [0 0]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',XLABEL);
set(gca,'XTick',XLABEL );
```

Anyone can help or give any tips ?.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Create your graph, then

```
length(get(gca,'Xticklabel'))
```

will tell you how long the XTickLabel is

For me, when I try a 3 element errorbar plot, it is 7 long.

then do:

```
 set(gca,'XtickLabel',{'' '9' '' '15' '' '23' ''})
```

this will put empty values in the place of the 0.5, 1.5 etc, and the correct strings for labels on your graph.

Of course, if your XTickLabel has a different length, you may need to adjust the position of the blank labels, etc.